# Java multi-threadning works in Windows but not in Ubuntu

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, unix

I have created a SIP-XMPP gateway with "Smack API" (XMPP) and "JAIN SIP" API (SIP). In my application I have three threads: one for sending and receiving SIP, one for sending and receiving XMPP and one "MessageQueue" for storing incoming messages and redirect them to the opposite protocol-thread (incoming SIP -> outgoing XMPP, incoming XMPP -> outgoing SIP)

[image]

I'm currently running the gateway in Eclipse on my Windows computer and it totally works. But if i export the Eclipse project to a .jar file and run it on my Ubuntu server, incoming messages gets stored in the message queue but they're not redirected.

[image]

I'm running the application with the same JDK version "1.6.0_14" on both OS. I've read that threads in Java run slightly different in Windows and UNIX systems. Am i doing something wrong or does the threads run different pending on what OS it runs under?

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue();

XMPPMessageListener xmppThread = new XMPPMessageListener();
SIPThread sipThread = new SIPThread();

new Thread(queue).start();

sipThread.setQueue(queue);
xmppThread.setQueue(queue);

queue.setXMPPThread(xmppThread);
queue.setSipThread(sipThread);

new Thread(xmppThread).start();
new Thread(sipThread).start();
```

Comment: Hard to tell. Is the app just hanging there on subsequent messages? If so, you should do a thread dump when it is hanging.

Comment: You could be running into thread safety issues which could present themselves differently based on conditions of the environment (performance, etc).  Are you using concurrent queue classes in your MessageQueue class?  Also, why are you passing the 2 worker threads to your queue?

Comment: Java threads are not *required* to time slice. That is, the scheduler need not preemptively suspend a thread to give another a chance to run. Perhaps your program design or implementation assumes that threads time slice?

Comment: @Raedwald good point, but i'm pretty sure that time slice is not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On both OSs, a dead-lock free program without data races should behave correctly. However, the OS are different enough that a potential data race or deadlock may realise itself on one OS with a higher probability than on the other.

There is a tiny possibility that your prgram is correct and the Windows JVM is correct, but the UNIX JVM has a bug.

However, you better make sure your program is indeed correct. From what you told, the best guess is that it is hanging in the MessageQueue thread, or in the sipThread. A thread dump will tell you more.

Comment: I ended up running my application on a Windows server instead of a Ubuntu server. I'm not sure if it's my application or the Java JDK version is the root of the problem but i read that threads in Windows are slightly more lightweight and may perform slightly better within single process applications than in UNIX. I'm gonna do some more research and perhaps do some corrections on my application